# Spring batch datareader returns extra null object on end of collection of read items?

Tags: java, datareader, spring-batch

I'm using Spring batch - using datareaders to load up lists of items. For each of my readers, they all return an extra null object on the end of the list.

Has anybody seen this before? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You'll need to give more information than this. Such as: what's the data source? It might get more traction to provide some code, even if you have to dumb it down to get an example that illustrates your problem.

You might find that just tinkering with isolating the problem will help you figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

It's the normal behavior.

A reader stops on a null element.
But to find a null element, you must find it.
As a consequence, the null element is issued, but it will the last one and the writer won't be called.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you were implementing the `read()` method from the `ItemReader` 
http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemReader.html

What you want to do is implement the `readCursor(ResultSet rs, int currentRow)` method from the `JdbcCursorItemTeader` - this will stop this behaviour. 
http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcCursorItemReader.html